# Why did the Dominion not start the war over again after the treaty?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-dominion

After the war with the Dominion in the Alpha and Beta Quadrant was over, a peace treaty was signed. The female shapeshifter signs the documents with contempt. Surely in their view that treaty is just a formality.

What prevents the Dominion from building up a massive fleet in the Gamma Quadrant and starting the war again? As said in DS9, the Dominion had the ability to breed Jem'hadar fast and also build ships fast.

Comment: This sounds like a discussions of your opinions about Deep Space Nine, as opposed to an actual question.

Comment: There are two different (on-topic) questions here; "*Why would the 2800 ships of the Dominion turn the tide against the Alpha Quadrant forces?"* and "*Why would the Dominion respect the Peace treaty and not simply try again later?"*

Comment: If you're going to use a peace treaty as a delay tactic to build up ships, you'd best build enough to take on *the whole galaxy*, because **no one is going to trust your word after a stunt like that.**  Even the Cardassians and the Breen might not have stuck with the Dominion at that point, and I'm not sure that it's clear the Dominion could win without them if they left.

Comment: I shortened the question to ask first about the possibility for the Dominion to rebuild their fleet in the Gamma Quadrant.

Comment: This is very answerable

Comment: For @Valorum everything is answerable :) but this question is answerable for ordinary people too :)